# Confusion between "rvalue" and "rvalue reference" in book

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference, rvalue

(I searched for *[c++] "functional programming in c++" book*, which give only 4 unrelevant results.)

I'm reading *Functional Programming in C++* from [Ivan Čukić](https://cukic.co/), and at page 118 there's a sentence which I'm not sure I've understood. The section is about rvalue and lvalue overloads of member functions, and the sentence is the following, where *the second overload* is the one using the `&&` reference type qualifier:

> The second overload will be called on objects from which you're allowed to stead the data -- temporary objects *and other rvalue **references***.

My doubts are these:

- the part in *italic* puzzles me in the first place, as in *what else could it be if not a temporary?*, but maybe this is just because I still haven't got a firm understanding of what xvalues are;
- the word in **bold** really puzzles me, in that the sentence seems meaningful to me only if I **remove** that word.

The code below is for support of my understanding.

Indeed, my understanding is that if I say *rvalue reference*, I'm talking about a function parameter (so it has a name; example: `a` in the free function `f`'s declaration) declared as rvalue reference to the actual argument, or a variable that I have declared (so it has a name; example: `rr`) as an rvalue reference to another variable; (fwiw, both referenc-**ed** entities must be rvalues, otherwise the reference would not bind). In either case, since it has a name, calling the member function `f` on it, would result in calling the lvalue overload, wouldn't it?

So is there a miswording in the book or am I missing something?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  void f() &  { std::cout << "lvalue\n"; } // const & in the book, but it shouldn't make any difference
  void f() && { std::cout << "rvalue\n"; }
};

void f(A&& a) { a.f(); } // a is an lvalue (of type rvalue ref to)

int main() {
  A a;          // "normal" object
  A&& rr = A{}; // rvalue reference to a temporary (with life extended)

  a.f();
  A{}.f(); // only here I expect the rvalue overload to be called, and this is the case
  f(A{});
  rr.f();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the word in **bold** really puzzles me, in that the sentence seems meaningful to me only if I **remove** that word.

I agree. IMO to be more precise the sentence should be

*The second overload will be called on objects from which you're allowed to stead the data -- rvalues (prvalues or xvalues).*

*Rvalue reference* is used for types, *rvalue* is used for [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), they're independent things. In this case, which overload will be called depends on value category, i.e. the object to be called on is an lvalue or rvalue, which has nothing to do with its type.

> the part in *italic* puzzles me in the first place, as in *what else could it be if not a temporary*?, but maybe this is just because I still haven't got a firm understanding of what xvalues are;

Yes, xvalues are rvalues too. Given `int x = 0;` `std::move(x)` is an xvalue but it's not a temporary.

Comment: Perhaps it's intuitive to think of xvalues as being just like lvalues (both are glvalues and both refer to existing objects), but the only difference is *intent*. An lvalue refers to object that you intend should remain useable later, and an xvalue refers to an object that you no longer "care" about.

Comment: Also note that expressions *never* have reference types. Any expression that would have a reference type (e.g. a function call when the return type of the function is given as a reference type) has that reference removed from its type and its value category adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @HTNW, a link in support of your second comment would be much appreciated, as it would help me understand this topic.

Comment: So the expression `std::move(x)` is of type rvalue reference to `x` and its value category is rvalue. Am I right?

Comment: @HTNW you need to either back up that claim or be more specific. `decltype( fn() )` definitely returns a reference type with the declaration `T& fn()`.

Comment: @ZuodianHu `decltype` *doesn't* actually give you the type of an expression! `decltype` *combines* type and value category information by using reference types: prvalues get no reference, lvalues get `&`, and xvalues get `&&`. My earlier comment is directly based in [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#1). The fact that `decltype` "lies" is also taken from [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype).

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis No. In the example given in this answer, `std::move(x)` has type `int` and category xvalue. The expression `x` itself has type `int` and category lvalue. `std::move` "casts" from category lvalue to category xvalue without changing the type. "rvalue" is shorthand for "prvalue or xvalue"; it is correct to say that `std::move(x)` is an rvalue but it is more specific to say that it is an xvalue. The fact that casts from lvalue to xvalue and back again are zero-cost is what motivates saying that they're really the same kind of thing, only differing in intent.

Comment: _IMO to be more precise the sentence should be..._ It confuses objects with expressions.